# Generics and "Unchecked call to 'add(E)' as a member of raw type 'java.util.ArrayList'"

Tags: java, android, generics

I'm getting an "Unchecked call to 'add(E)' as a member of raw type 'java.util.ArrayList'" warning in leftNode.next.add line. Anyone know how to make my compiler happy?

```
public static class Node<T extends Node> {
    int id;
    T previous;
    ArrayList<T> next = new ArrayList<>();

    protected Node(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static void connect(Node leftNode, Node rightNode) {
        leftNode.next.add(rightNode);
        rightNode.previous = leftNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not tag your questions with languages that have nothing to do with your question

Comment: My mistake, I've been programming in too many languages and it seems it is taking its toll. Sorry again should've been #java

Comment: Your Node parameters in the connect method are not generic, i.e. you're using Node instead of Node<Some Type>, that's why node.next is missing the same generic type

Comment: Hmm... does that mean that the code above is equivalent to Node class declaration (not the template/generics)? And also, does that mean that static connect method is a regular function?

Comment: I've made a quick read about generics/static methods etc and came up with the following solution, but still I get the same warning. Solution: public static <I extends Node> void connect(I leftNode, I rightNode)

Comment: You're solution has the same problem, I extends raw Node, not generic node, generics in java aren't good tbh, so you'll likely have to come up with another solution

Comment: I mean the code works, still it would've been nice if I got rid of this warning and know the solution. To be honest, I don't know what the fuss is about, as all in all Node<T> specifically states T derives from Node and if so, then why the warning in connect when classes derived from Node are passed as arguments. Ergh..